# Single Kubernetes/OpenShift cluster/instance across datacenters?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin

As posted on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34194602/2408961) (not sure which community is best suited?)

With the understanding that Ubernetes is designed to fully solve this problem, is it currently possible (not necessarily recommended) to span a single K8/OpenShift cluster across multiple internal corporate datacententers?

Additionally assuming that latency between data centers is relatively low and that infrastructure across the corporate data centers is relatively consistent.

Example: Given 3 corporate DC's, deploy 1..* masters at each datacenter (as a single cluster) and have 1..* nodes at each DC with pods/rc's/services/... being spun up across all 3 DC's.

Has someone implemented something like this as a stop gap solution before Ubernetes drops and if so, how has it worked and what would be some considerations to take into account on running like this?

Comment: You can put nodes in different regions. But the OpenShift SDN doesn't have any concept of region yet. So...kind of not really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a fair number of people deploying like this.  Keep latency low between etcd instances, spread machines across AZs, and plan for failure.  You can isolate SDN even between regions if you wish - simply disallow traffic between those nodes and ensure the masters don't get tricked into bridging the traffic.  If you're deploying a flat network instead of SDN (host subnet mode), it's even easier.  Be sure to set your nodes in each AZ with the region and zone labels to ensure spreading (you can customize these labels, of course).